# asp.net MVC 5 - Unable to access items in list, in view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm making a web app in MVC similar to Change.org, where users can create causes for other people to sign. In my cause index view I am trying to display a list of people who have signed the caused. I can use Count on the List to display the number of signatures, but I am struggling to access the item within the List to display them. Any help on this would be much appreciated.

My models are split into Cause, Signature and Category like so...

Cause:

```
public class Cause
{   

    [Key]
    [StringLength(100)]
    [DisplayName("Cause Title")]
    public string CauseTitle { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(500)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string UserEmail { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Date Posted")]
    public DateTime DatePosted { get; set; }
    public string ImageURL { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Catagory")]
    public string CatagoryTitle { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CatagoryTitle")]
    public Catagory Catagory { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Signatures Target")]
    public int TargetSignatures { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Signature> Signatures { get; set; }
}
```

Catagory:

```
public class Catagory
{   
    [DisplayName("Catagory Title")]
    [Key]
    public string CatagoryTitle { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Catagory Description")]
    public string CatagoryDescription { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Cause> Causes { get; set; }
}
```

Signature:

```
public class Signature
{
    [Key]
    public int SignatureId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string UserEmail { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string CauseTitle { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CauseTitle")]
    public virtual Cause Cause { get; set; }

}
```

My Cause Index Controller is:

```
 public class CausesController : Controller
{
    private CauseContext db = new CauseContext();

    // GET: Causes
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var causes = db.Causes.Include(c => c.Catagory);
        return View(causes.ToList());
    }
```

and my Index View is:

```
    @model IEnumerable<SoWokeWebApp.Models.Cause.Cause>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<div class="jumbotron">
    <img src="@item.ImageURL" alt="Alternate Text" class="img-fluid" />
    <h1>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.CauseTitle)</h1>
    <p>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Description)</p>
    <p>@item.Signatures.Count</p>
    @foreach (var Signature in item.Signatures)
    {
        <p>Signature.</p>
    }
    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">@Html.ActionLink("Sign Cause", "Create", "Signatures")</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: `<p>@Signature.LastName, @Signature.FirstName</p>`?

Comment: Yep. So simple. Feel like an idiot. That's a sign I probably need to take a break lol. Thanks!

Comment: @p.s.w.g can you post as Answer?

Answer (score 0):

Did you debugged the code and checked if the the signature data is coming or not?. I think you have to include the signature list in the model of index method.